# Highmaps occuring 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ' and not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying use Highmaps with Highchart.Highcharts working perfectly but highmaps doesnt work with highmaps.

Highmaps not loading with highchart graphic.And thoring 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ' error on console.I assume that its  javascript confilict error.But How can I fix this?

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);

        // Correct UK to GB in data
        $.each(data, function () {
            if (this.code === 'UK') {
                this.code = 'GB';
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
            chart : {
                borderWidth : 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'World population 2010 by country'
            },

            subtitle : {
                text : 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name: 'Countries',
                mapData: mapData,
                color: '#E0E0E0',
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }, {
                type: 'mapbubble',
                mapData: mapData,
                name: 'Population 2010',
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                data: data,
                minSize: 4,
                maxSize: '12%',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Sorry for writing this.Yes jquery is loaded.

Comment: Well for me its working: http://jsfiddle.net/e0vb1vzs/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jquery.min.js before other highmaps plugin

```js
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);

        // Correct UK to GB in data
        $.each(data, function () {
            if (this.code === 'UK') {
                this.code = 'GB';
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
            chart : {
                borderWidth : 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'World population 2010 by country'
            },

            subtitle : {
                text : 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name: 'Countries',
                mapData: mapData,
                color: '#E0E0E0',
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }, {
                type: 'mapbubble',
                mapData: mapData,
                name: 'Population 2010',
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                data: data,
                minSize: 4,
                maxSize: '12%',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```